# Force emails not to be grouped into conversations

Tags: gmail, sendmail, email, incoming-mail

My website sends emails to me with the same subject and they are being grouped into conversations even if I delete old ones (Mail, Gmail). I know I can change the subject to prevent this, but is there a header or something else that can be added to do this without forcing unique subject lines?

Comment: gmail grouping infuriates me.  Maybe I am too old school and like to read oldest to newest.  I don't get gmail grouping.

Comment: ojblass, it can be turned off in your preferences. But I need something that works from the sending side.

Answer (score 54):

On the top of my head, there are two methods to avoid threading:

- set the SMTP header `X-Entity-Ref-ID` with any value. This is what Google+ notifications do.
- change the sender email (you can use `From: info+randomstring@example.com`). This is what Facebook notifications do.

The threading will be made if you force it with `Reference` or `Reply-To`.

Comment: YES! Wow, this is saving me a ton of hair-pulling. All the other answers I found to this question were adding random numbers to subject lines - I don't want to send that to my users! And GMAIL destroys the css on my HTML emails. THANK YOU RDS!

Comment: Wow, thanks for this but, how do you know about `X-Entity-Ref-ID` ? is it a gmail only thing ? I can't find anybody else talking about this in the internet :)

Comment: `X-` are private fields, so this one is likely to be Gmail specific only.

Comment: The SMTP headers are visible in any message.

Comment: The X-Entity-Ref-ID did not work for me;  +randomstring did!  Thx.

Comment: For me `X-Entity-Ref-ID: null` did work, both for GMail as well as a client like Airmail.

Comment: Oh my god - thank you so much for that X-Entity-Ref-ID trick! Been pulling my hair out with this issue for two days.

Answer (score 0):

The situation has changed since 2019.

I found a solution in https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html.

Setting a header of the form `References: <---uuid---@youremailproviderhere.com>`, with a unique UUID for each email is enough to solve this.

Tested a few times today and I confirm it works.

Comment: Unsure if it works – I get emails threaded even in the absence of an `X-Entity-Ref-ID` header. Just same title and sender seem enough.