# Which headers to set when sending emails with an API to avoid emails to be thread-grouped in Gmail client

Tags: email, gmail, incoming-mail

Let's say I send customized/different emails for 20 persons with my email provider API.

But all emails have the exact same subject (let's say `"Hello"`), and this cannot be changed.

These emails are sent to 20 different persons, but also as BCC to myself (example@gmail.com) so that I keep a copy in my inbox.

How to avoid these 20 emails to be grouped in the same thread?
(Note: I don't want to disable `Conversation view` for the Gmail client).

My email provider offers to add custom email `Headers`.

**Which headers to set in an email so that emails with same topic, same sender, are not grouped in the same thread in the Gmail client?**

Linked topic: [Force emails not to be grouped into conversations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23434110/force-emails-not-to-be-grouped-into-conversations).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2019/03/threading-changes-in-gmail-conversation-view.html.

Setting a header of the form `References: <uuid@youremailproviderhere.com>`, with a unique UUID for each email is enough to solve this.